# how to make a get request to data from response_url of slack api

Tags: axios, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am using the slack api in a typescript application, where when I initially send a payload through a slack / command, this payload has a response_url. I am able to post data to this response_url with axios, but I have trouble making a get request to this url to access the data I have previously posted. I have tried `axios.get(response_url)` and `await axios.get(response_url)` but I have gotten invoke error with status code 500 and a result of `Promise {<pending>}` - would anyone know the correct way to use the get call?

Comment: the `reponse_url` is a webhook, it is not a rest api that can be queried. What are you trying to do? The POST to your server contains a `command` field with the slash command and a `text` with everything after the command. There are more fields listed in the [api](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands) if you need them.

Comment: After I use the / command, a lambda function is activated. I initially wanted to make a post request to the response_url containing the data from the initial payload, so that I could later make a get request to that url in order to retrieve the data. However, if I cannot do this would you know of another way I could possibly 'save' the initial payload for later use?

Comment: Not sure why you would need a history of what you sent so it's difficult to help. You could store the response in a database or cache on your server side. There is a [slack conversation history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) call among other history calls, but you'd need to know the conversation ID or other details so you'd have to store that.